# Как построить функцию linear как функцию активации из tensorflow.keras.layers Activation?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, keras

```
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras import utils   



def createModel():
      model = Sequential() #Созадём сеть
      #Добавляем слои
      model.add(Dense(800, input_dim=784, activation="relu"))
      model.add(Dense(10, activation="linear"))
      model.add(Dense(10, activation="softmax"))
      #Компилируем сеть
      model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])

      #Созвращаем созданную сеть
      return model
```

Нашла как строить график relu:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def plot(func, name_of_func:str, label:str):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
    fig.clear()
    X = np.linspace(-30, 30, 1000)
    y = func(X)

    plt.plot(X, 
             y, 
             label=label, 
             color='blue', 
             linewidth=3)

    plt.xlabel('x', fontsize=30)
    plt.ylabel('y', fontsize=30)
    plt.title(name_of_func, fontsize=30)
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize=30)
def relu(x:np.ndarray):
    return np.where(x >= 0, x, 0)
relu_label = r'$\sigma(x) = relu(x)$'
plot(relu, 'RELU', relu_label)
```

Как построить график linear из tensorflow.keras.layers как функции активации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот исходный код функции активации [keras.activations.linear()](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/activations.py#L187-L196):

```
def linear(x):
    """Linear (i.e. identity) activation function.
    # Arguments
        x: Input tensor.
    # Returns
        Input tensor, unchanged.
    """
    return x
```

Т.е. данная функция возвращает неизменным переданный ей аргумент `x`.

PS врядли стоит чертить график данной функции... ;)